# QML Qt openUrlExternally

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qml

I've just discovered strange behavior when using this code

```
Qt.openUrlExternally(someurl);
```

I would like to let my users open facebook sharer url,
but I cannot use this code, as it does nothing.

Tested on S60 5th and Symbian^3 devices (C5, C7, 5230, N8)

So please tell me (if you know)
1) **Is there any BUG about this component/behavior ?** (I searched and didn't found anything)
2) **How can i make C++ component to do the same thing ?`** (If it is solution)

Thanks

**Edit**
I found example for creating C++ components with methods accessible to QML, right here:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-declarative-cppextensions-referenceexamples-methods-example.html

**Final Edit**

Discussion led to making a bug report, could be found on : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19201

Thanks everybody

Comment: Marek, I have just encountered this issue in my own code, `Qt.openUrlExternally` seems to not work on any URL containing `?` or `&`.  Did you ever find an actual solution to this?

Comment: @funkybro: I'm using calls with `?` and `&` without problems, like this `Qt.openUrlExternally(voucher_link+"?voucher=pdf");`, so your problem has to be caused by something else. Try making separate thread for your problem, and you'll see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Qt.openUrlExternally("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");` opens the native browser for me.

The only problem I have found with it is, if the browser is already running on the handset (in the background), it will not be brought in to the foreground, and therefore looks as though it has had no effect.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like some bug in platform Qt/QML. Most probable this one: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-8336

Comment: That link is dead. Instead visit: http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8336

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this to your .pro file

```
# Needed for bringing browser from background to foreground using QDesktopServices: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8336
TARGET.CAPABILITY += SwEvent
```

And it should bring the browser to the foreground.