# Qt.openUrlExternally() sometimes works on Symbian^3 and sometimes not, why is this?

Tags: qt, symbian, qml, qt-quick

I am having some difficulty with [`Qt.openUrlExternally`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qml-qt.html#openUrlExternally-method) on Symbian^3.  Sometimes it works, sometimes not, and I can't find any pattern to it.

Another user seems to be having the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960192/qml-qt-openurlexternally).

When it does not work, the actual behaviour is that a web browser opens, comes to the foreground briefly (for a few seconds), then goes to the background.  It is still open, but the URL does not load.

`Qt.openUrlExternally("http://www.stackoverflow.com")` **works**.

`Qt.openUrlExternally("http://twitter.com/share?text=ZOMG")` **fails**.  I initially concluded that this meant any URL with `?` does not work, however this is wrong because...

`Qt.openUrlExternally("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=ZOMG")` **works**.  However, it seems to work for one word only because:

`Qt.openUrlExternally("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Will%20this%20work")` **fails**.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue (specifically for sending arbitrary text to Twitter I suppose), and what have they done about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, had an result on this on the [Qt forum](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8621/).  `Qt.openUrlExternally` does not seem to like URLs containing `%20` as an escaped space. `+` works.  (This brought to my attention that my second assertion above was wrong, `http://twitter.com/share?text=ZOMG` does work).

The solution seems to be to pass the URI parameter through Javascript's `encodeURIComponent()` function and replace all resulting `%20`s with `+`s.